# Angular HttpClient get request no return in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

i want to implement a Login. Therfore I made a get request for getting the user information and write them into localstorage, but somehow it never gets to the point where I want to call setItem.

AuthenticationService.ts

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(username, password) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('' + username + ':' + password + ''),
      }),
    };
    this.http.get('api/user/loginInfo', httpOptions).subscribe((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res));
    });
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  login() {
    const username = (document.getElementById('username') as HTMLInputElement)
      .value;
    const password = (document.getElementById('password') as HTMLInputElement)
      .value;
    this.authService.login(username, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `login(username, password)` ever called? If so: do you see the request in the development console (e.g., in Developer Tools using Chrome)? Is the request successful, or do you get an error?

Comment: yeah, all works  fine if i make a breakpoint on the line where the get request is. Edit: and yeah in the dev console is nothing to see.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, the functionality is working as intended and without a breakpoint it isn't? Or did I miss the point of your comment?

Comment: yeah exactly, with breakpoint it works, without not.

Comment: That does not seem right, as a breakpoint should not modify the behavior of your code. How did you make sure that the key/value pair is not set without a breakpoint?

Comment: If there is no breakpoint, the localstorage stay complete empty.

Comment: Are you removing the key somewhere immediately after you store it? Please show how this code is invoked.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake. I called the methode from a Form and somehow there is a problem. I've now removed the form-tag in the html and everything works now.